# Power Off Monitors at Logoff

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, electrical-power, logoff-scripts

Mixed domain environment, xp, vista, 7
DC = Server 2003, 2008

Has anyone done this ? powering off the Monitor when a user shutsdown the machine or logs off ?

I have checked the GPO Setting but they seem to be focused on when the machine is idle or on different powersources - I am after a way to power-down the monitor as and when a User shuts down the machine when finishing work ?

Any suggestions / help would be great !
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The monitor should go into "sleep" mode when the computer is turned off, and that is all that happens if the display is turned "off" by the Windows energy saver; it just means that the graphics card turns off the sync signal, prompting the power saver mode on most monitors.

As far as I know there is no standard method to really turn off a monitor from the computer, but I guess there might be some models that are controllable via USB or something, but this is certainly not standard and not controllable via GPO.

Comment: So, basically, if I setup the Power Scheme via GPO then set the settings to "Turn off Display After 10 Minutes" that would do as you have mentioned "graphics card turns off the sync signal, prompting power saver mode on most monitors" and the same would happen once the user shuts down there pc at end of the day ?
Thanks so much for your prompt response.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The monitor is not really off then, but consumes only very little energy.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response ; This is what I thought initially that how can one power down a monitor via GPO or a script at log off and all I could think off was to use the Power Scheme as I mentioned.

Thanks again SvenW.

Comment: When a PC is powered off, monitors will automatically sleep, regardless of OS settings.